# How to deal with single or double quote in string variable in Access SQL expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, parameterized-query

I wrote this line in c# to operate microsoft access database

```
OleDbCommand sComm = new OleDbCommand
  ("Update TableToBeImport set TextDefault = '" + resxValue + "' 
    WHERE ControlName = '" + resxKey + "'" , c);
```

`resxValue`  and `resxKey`  are all string variable.

when the two string variables are simple such as "abc","xyz", things are OK, but when one string variable become complex, in my case, like this:

TIPS:

1. To fix rate plan & rpt error use 'reprocess'
2. To fix carrier,trunk group,trader error, use 'delete and reinsert'

the program throws an error, and when i doing debug, the sComm.CommandText is this form:

> Update TableToBeImport set TextDefault = 'TIPS: \r\n1. To fix rate plan 
>   & rpt error use 'reprocess'\r\n2. To fix carrier,trunk group,trader error,
>   use 'delete and reinsert'' WHERE ControlName = 'frmCDRQuery.label7.Text'

I know in c#, I can use `@` before a string variable, so any escape character in it will be ignored. But in accesss, how can I get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
var resxValue = ""; // obviously this will be whatever the type and value that is required
var resxKey = ""; // obviously this will be whatever the type and value that is required

// I am assuming here that you are already programming with a `using` statement
using (OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection(""))
{
    using (OleDbCommand sComm = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE TableToBeImport SET TextDefault = @p0 WHERE ControlName = @p1", c))
    {
        sComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@p0", resxValue));
        sComm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@p1", resxKey));

        // rest of your code here E.G., sComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```